# after dragging the existing table row create new table and append the row to new table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

```
.directive('dbDraggablenew', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      link: function(scope, element) {
        $(element).draggable({ 
            helper: function(){
            var selected = $('.childgrid tr.selectedRow');
            if (selected.length === 0) {
              selected = $(this).addClass('selectedRow');
            }
            var container = $('<div/>').attr('id', 'draggingContainer');
            container.append(selected.clone().removeClass("selectedRow"));
            return container;
          }
         });
      }
    };
  });
```

so what will be the drop function??